# Sniff SMTP with Scapy Python

Tags: python, smtp, scapy

I am tring to recognize smtp sessions being started in my sniffed network using scapy I have already classified http, udp, tcp, dns and tried:

```
recog_smtp = lambda pkt: SMTP in pkt
```

But it's not working, it shows fake SMTP packets(made a check with WS and there wasn't any SMTP packets)

Comment: Are you sure if you are generating SMTP traffic? How are you generating the SMTP traffic? Try wireshark to confirm if there is any SMTP traffic.

Comment: well apperantly that printing wasn't the problem, it prints SMTP but i checked with wireshark and there wasn't any SMTP sessions were made while it said that there was.